# Pi randomly rebooting

Tags: boot, hard-drive, boot-issues

Sometimes my Pi restarts suddenly, I think it's because too many USB devices are connected and not enough power is being supplied to the Pi.

When it restarts, it asks me to press F1, (or some key) to check the attached USB hard drive for errors. That's nice, but I can't swap it to my other room, attach it to a screen, press that key, put it back, restart again...

I'm fine with it checking the drive but I don't want to have to press that key every time it does a restart.

What configuration do I have to apply to let it do its tests without me pressing  a key?

(I'll get a picture of it in a second)

Update:

The SD Card broke and the Pi doesn't boot anymore. As I'm still interested in an answer to the question I'll leave it open.

Comment: You cannot (reliably) run a USB HD without a powered hub (unless the drive has its own power). If you keep trying you will corrupt the HD and SD card (which you have apparently already done).

Comment: @Milliways It has its own power.

Comment: What power supply were you using for your Pi?